# Expresion regular busca 2 cadenas en misma línea

Tags: regex

Espero me puedan ayudar, necesito  obtener con expresiones regulares todas las líneas que tenga la palabra "GET" y la palabra "php"

He intentado varias combinaciones, pero no me funciona. Por ejemplo:

```
(GET)+(php)+

(GET)(php)

(GET).(php)
```

Parte del ejemplo del archivo donde estoy buscando.

```
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:02 -0400] "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 110
201.239.202.201 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:02 -0400] "POST /include/traspaso/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 324
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /persona/fichas/ficha.php HTTP/1.1" 200 54458
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /css/iconos.css HTTP/1.1" 200 218
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /js/librerias/bootstrap3-dialog-master/css/bootstrap-dialog.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2554
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /js/librerias/turbo/assets/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 13997
201.239.202.201 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /persona/fichas/ficha.php HTTP/1.1" 200 62494
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /css/DataTables/demo_page.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1276
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /css/DataTables/demo_table.css HTTP/1.1" 200 12571
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /js/librerias/bootstrap3-dialog-master/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 13973
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /js/formulario/funEnviarFormulario.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3490
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /js/librerias/bootstrap3-dialog-master/js/bootstrap-dialog.js HTTP/1.1" 200 31864
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /js/librerias/turbo/assets/vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 34172
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /js/librerias/turbo/assets/vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 513
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /js/librerias/jquery.select-bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 200 70101
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /js/componentes/alertas/alerta.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4134
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /imagen/Logo-color(2).png HTTP/1.1" 200 8836
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /imagen/isotipo-color.png HTTP/1.1" 200 28367
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /imagen/logo-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 33525
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /css/nav-print.css HTTP/1.1" 200 4749
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /include/mostrar/incFoto.php?ii_id=18359258 HTTP/1.1" 200 4320
201.216.141.227 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:03 -0400] "GET /js/librerias/turbo/assets/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3 HTTP/1.1" 200 71896
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /css/DataTables/demo_page.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1276
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /css/iconos.css HTTP/1.1" 200 218
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /css/DataTables/demo_table.css HTTP/1.1" 200 12571
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /persona/fichas/ficha.php HTTP/1.1" 200 55103
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /js/formulario/funEnviarFormulario.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3490
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /imagen/Logo-color(2).png HTTP/1.1" 200 8836
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /imagen/isotipo-color.png HTTP/1.1" 200 28367
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /css/nav-print.css HTTP/1.1" 200 4749
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /imagen/logo-nave.png HTTP/1.1" 200 33525
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /include/mostrar/incFoto?ii_id=1888505 HTTP/1.1" 200 3357
190.101.168.239 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "POST /materia/registro_calificaciones/registro.php HTTP/1.1" 200 15
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /js/librerias/bootstrap3-dialog-master/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 13973
190.165.327.232 - - [08/Jul/2020:00:02:05 -0400] "GET /js/librerias/bootstrap3-dialog-master/js/bootstrap-dialog.js HTTP/1.1" 200 31864
```

Si me pueden ayudar, genial!!! Ojalá explicando que estaba haciendo mal.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. Agrega el código de la expresión regular con la que has intentado. Revisa [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Para este caso puede servirte, `.+` para indicar que cualqier expresion puede existir entre estas dos palabras

```
(GET).+(php)
```

Usando `preg_match()`:

```
if (preg_match("/(GET).+(php)/",$linea) { 
 // coincidencia
}
```

De todas maneras, si solo usas la expresion para hacer match y no para obtener los valores coincidentes (en este caso siempre seran GET y PHP), no necesitas los parentesis. Estos son para almacenar las concidencias puntuales de cada expresion entre ellas, ya sea para hacer reemplazos o extraer informacion.